# Help segmenting/isolate my network with VLANs

Tags: vlan, security

I have a couple of IP cameras (live view and recording via an NVR) and DVR (with analogue cameras) connected by ethernet on my network.
Nothing is separated atm; i.e. everything can access everything on the network.

Here is a diagram of my network:
[image]

So now I want to isolate the IP cameras and DVR (with analogue cameras) from my main network.

The issue is I have several IP cameras upstairs and downstairs and I have only one router capable of VLAN in my whole network.

The constraint:
Downstairs and upstairs are connected via a single cable. I can't connect the cameras upstairs directly to the router or switch downstairs due to physical constraints. Pretty much the same thing for all other devices upstairs

1. So how can I have a VLAN for all my cameras (upstairs and downstairs). I don't want my cameras to be able to access my main network and internet but my NVR downstairs need to be able to communicate with them.
   I feel like I need another route with VLAN capabilities or a managed switch?
2. If possible I would also like to isolate the smart TV and access point upstairs in another VLAN with some less strict restrictions: internet access and access to only certain services (ex. NAS and plex) on my main network.

Comment: VLAN is a layer 2 (I.E. switch) feature. Are your switches VLAN capable?

Comment: All switches are unmanaged on my network. Only device capable of VLAN is one router as shown in https://i.imgur.com/hPx5KBn.png

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices, such are your Asus and unmanaged switches, are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is I have several IP cameras upstairs and downstairs and I have only one router capable of VLAN in my whole network.
>
> The constraint: Downstairs and upstairs are connected via a single cable.

That won't work. An unmanaged switch can only be connected to a single VLAN. A connection can only be used for a single VLAN unless both sides support VLANs (=managed switches).

You'll need either

- two dedicated, unmanaged switches, one for each VLAN, plus a dedicated downlink to each switch
- a managed switch with VLANs to "partition" it

for upstairs and downstairs each.

Comment: that's what I thought. So I can use my existing Asus Router to create a VLAN for my downstairs IP cameras.
And I need to buy an additional router or switch with VLAN capaibilites for upstairs IP Cameras?

Comment: At the very least, yes. Can't say anything about the Asus router though, I don't know it and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to isolate devices, it's not enough to put them on separate VLANs.

In a routed environment, **VLAN separation alone will not isolate your devices.**

You need to apply an Access Control List (ACL) on the router interfaces to limit which VLANs are allowed to communicate with each other.  Different router models have different ways of doing this.